# should I return a pointer or a reference in C++ functions and classes?

Tags: c++, pointers, c++11, reference

What are the pros and cons of each, which is done under what circumstances?
Returning a reference or a pointer appears quite similar, I don't know which should really be done.

Comment: First related link on the right.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/57483/what-are-the-differences-between-pointer-variable-and-reference-variable-in-c?rq=1